# Refactoring Func<T> into Expression<Func<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I have a method that currently takes a `Func<Product, string>` as a parameter, but I need it to be an `Expression<Func<Product, string>>`.  Using AdventureWorks, here's an example of what I'd like to do using the Func.

```
private static void DoSomethingWithFunc(Func<Product, string> myFunc)
{
    using (AdventureWorksDataContext db = new AdventureWorksDataContext())
    {
        var result = db.Products.GroupBy(product => new
        {
            SubCategoryName = myFunc(product),
            ProductNumber = product.ProductNumber
        });
    }
}
```

I would like it to look something like this:

```
private static void DoSomethingWithExpression(Expression<Func<Product, string>> myExpression)
{
    using (AdventureWorksDataContext db = new AdventureWorksDataContext())
    {
        var result = db.Products.GroupBy(product => new
            {
                SubCategoryName = myExpression(product),
                ProductNumber = product.ProductNumber
            });
    }
}
```

However, the problem I'm running into is that `myExpression(product)` is invalid (won't compile).  After reading some other posts I understand why.  And if it wasn't for the fact that I need the `product` variable for the second part of my key I could probably say something like this:

```
var result = db.Products.GroupBy(myExpression);
```

But I do need the `product` variable because I do need the second part of the key (ProductNumber).  So I'm not really sure what to do now.  I can't leave it as a Func because that causes problems.  I can't figure out how to use an Expression because I don't see how I could pass it the `product` variable.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Here's an example of how I would call the method:

```
DoSomethingWithFunc(product => product.ProductSubcategory.Name);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to splice an expression tree that is represented as an `Expression<T>` object into a middle of a "tree literal" represented by lambda expression. You'll have to construct an expression tree to pass to `GroupBy` manually:

```
// Need an explicitly named type to reference in typeof()
private class ResultType
{
     public string SubcategoryName { get; set; }
     public int ProductNumber { get; set; }|
}

private static void DoSomethingWithExpression(
    Expression<Func<Product,
    string>> myExpression)
{
    var productParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "product");
    var groupExpr = (Expression<Func<Product, ResultType>>)Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.MemberInit(
           Expression.New(typeof(ResultType)),
           Expression.Bind(
               typeof(ResultType).GetProperty("SubcategoryName"),
               Expression.Invoke(myExpression, productParam)),
           Expression.Bind(
               typeof(ResultType).GetProperty("ProductNumber"),
               Expression.Property(productParam, "ProductNumber"))),
        productParam);
    using (AdventureWorksDataContext db = new AdventureWorksDataContext())
    {
        var result = db.Products.GroupBy(groupExpr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  The last line isn't compiling for me, though, where result is assigned to.  "The type arguments for method ... cannot be inferred from the usage."  Am I missing something?

Comment: The return value from `Expression.Lambda` should be cast to `Expression<Func<Product, ResultType>>`.

Comment: Excellent!  This turned out to more complex than I was expecting.  I've never made my own Expression like that before, so I'll be studying this code to make sure I fully understand what's going on.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah--it's never too soon to learn how to manually build expression trees; there are many common scenarios that all but demand it...

Comment: Looks like you could also say 

    Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, ResultType>>(...

rather than casting.

Answer (score 3):

On second thought, compiling the expression won't work.

You'll need to build your GroupBy expression by hand, which means you can't use anonymous type. I would suggest building out the rest of your expression and then decompiling to see the generated expression tree. The end result will look something like this, using parts of `myExpression` as appropriate:

```
private static void DoSomethingWithExpression(Expression<Func<Product, string>> myExpression)
{
    var productParam = myExpression.Parameters[0];

    ConstructorInfo constructor = ...; // Get c'tor for return type

    var keySelector = Expression.Lambda(
                          Expression.New(constructor,
                              new Expression[] {
                                  productParam.Body,
                                  ... // Expressions to init other members
                              },
                              new MethodInfo[] { ... }), // Setters for your members
                          new [] { productParam });

    using (AdventureWorksDataContext db = new AdventureWorksDataContext())
    {
        var result = db.Products.GroupBy(keySelector);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed the reason why he's moving from `Func` to `Expression` in the first place - he wants this to work in LINQ to SQL context, and that won't permit random function (or delegate) calls in a query.

Comment: You beat Pavel to the punch but his answer was more clear to me.  +1 for your help, though.  Thanks!

Comment: Agreed that Pavel's answer is better. I based my code on the expression generated for constructing an anonymous type; a MemberInit is what you want for a named type.